# Method Declaration Syntax

Tags: java

I've taken over a project and am running into coding style I haven't worked with much.

Can anyone explain how this works? Especially the clazz argument.

```
public <T extends Enum<T>> void activateLink(
    final Class<? extends Enum<T>> clazz,  final T linkName )
```

Comment: Which part of this declaration do you have problem with?

Comment: I'm unsure what the T extends Enum<T> means and the  Class<? extends Enum<T>> clazz. Why not just use "T<? extends Enum<T>> class for the argument. Basically, if you could explain the complete syntax of the method declartion that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

`Class<? extends Enum<T>> clazz`

I am guessing you're confused by the question mark? It just means "something that extends Enum". It works as a wildcard generic.

Comment: I understand that but what is the purpose of clazz. A Class object is being passed in. Couldn't the argument syntax just be T<? extends Enum<T> Class? And what does the <T extends Enum<T>> at the begining of the method stating? I think it means that only arguments of type T which extend Enum<T> (of type T> can be passed to the function. Is that correct?

Comment: Would you necessarily want clazz to be of type T? That depends on what the code does.

Comment: What determines the type of T? If it's generic, then couldn't it be anything you pass to the method?

Comment: @JoseyWhales No, because *anything* would violate the constraint on `T`, i.e. the `extends Enum<T>`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50069707/5221149).

Comment: @JoseyWhales `T` must be some `enum`.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have an `enum` like this:

```
enum Sex { Male, Female }
```

> I'm unsure what the `T extends Enum<T>` means

It means that `T` must be a type that extends `Enum<T>`.

`T` is a generic type parameter. If you don't know about generics, you need to read up on that first, e.g. [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Only `enum` types extends `Enum`, e.g. `Sex` implicitly extends `Enum<Sex>`, so it basically says that `T` must be an `enum`.

> I'm unsure what the `Class<? extends Enum<T>> clazz` means

It means a reference to an object of type `Class` for something (`?`) that extends `Enum<T>`.

This is not the same as `T`, but the type ("class") of `T`.

Since enums are implicitly final, that can only mean the class of the enum itself, e.g. `Sex.class`.

Here is an example call of the method:

```
activateLink(Sex.class, Sex.Male)
```

Here, the `T` type parameter is the actual type `Sex`, which means the method is equivalent to:

```
public void activateLink(final Class<? extends Enum<Sex>> clazz, final Sex linkName)
```

*FYI:* Unless the second parameter can be `null` (unlikely), requiring the `clazz` is redundant, since you can always get that by calling `linkName.getClass()`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Andeas. Could you tell me what determines the type of T? Or does it simply mean you can pass any type to the method?

Comment: @JoseyWhales The compiler will *infer* the type of `T`. The Java Language Specification has an entire chapter of how type inference works: [Chapter 18. Type Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html). In your case, it will be inferred from one of the parameters.

Comment: Thank you all for your explanations. I think I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

`<T extends Enum<T>>` means that your generic method is parameterized with the type variable `T` which extends `Enum<T>`. Basically, you have a type parameter `T` which is just some enum.

`Class<? extends Enum<T>> clazz` is the class of your enum. `? extends Enum<T>` means "some type which extends `Enum<T>` which we don't know or care about". The problem with generics is that they are erased, so sometimes if you really need to know the class of the type variable, you have to pass it explicitly.

However, in this case `clazz` can actually only be `Class<T>`. Because there is no other type extending `Enum<T>` other than `T`.

`final T linkName` - here you pass one of the values of the enum `T` or `null`. If `linkName` is not `null`, you won't really need the `Class<? extends Enum<T>> clazz` parameter, you could simply take `linkName.getClass()`. So this code probably assumes that `linkName` can be `null`.